# 'DOMAIN\Domain Users' group becomes 'SERVER\None' in Security Tab

Tags: security, certificate, windows-server-2008, active-directory-group, domaincontroller

I'm setting up a Domain Controller and another server for Certificates.

When I create a Certificate Template and go to the Security tab, I have a group called "Server\None" instead of "Domain\Domain Users".

All other default groups appear on that Security tab, but the group "Domain\Domain Users" does not appear.  Even when I remove "None" and manually add "Domain Users" it won't work.  As soon as I close the window and go back in, the Security tab shows "Server\None".

I can't get my Users to autoenroll and I think this is the cause, but I don't know why this group keeps becoming "None".

So, where does this "None" group come from, and how to fix it?

All servers are Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter.

Answer (score -1):

it's clear.
because you used a clone machine and joined it to the same domain as the source machine.
so these machines had same SID。
you should sysprep the cloned machine before joining the domain;

Comment: We are experiencing the same problem with a customer domain; brand new, all machines went through sysprep as a part of being deployed from a vmware template.